# Rename Availability Group and AG script

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability

I have two questions for you guys. I really appreciate your help.

1.- Is there a way to rename an Availability Group?

2.- Is there a way to get the T-SQL statements in order to re create a Availability Group in case that I need to drop it and create it again?

If there's information that you want me to share, please let me know and I will provide it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Once created an Availability Group (AG) cannot be renamed, although the databases within the AG can be renamed. You'd have to re-create it.
   See here for the options for ALTERing an AG: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878601.aspx
2. When creating the AG using the GUI (wizard), once all the steps are completed you will see a 'Script' button which gives the option to generate a script of those steps to a new window.
   You can then either save the script for later and quit the GUI, or just "finish" the wizard to actually create the AG. (The script will stay in the window)
   It's a good idea to keep the script in case it needs to be re-created later (e.g. if you want to rename the AG...)

It doesn't seem to be currently possible to "Script As..." an AG in the way you would for a table or stored procedure for example.

You could also write the CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP statement from scratch using the MSDN boilerplate code as a starting point (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878399.aspx) but that is likely to be very cumbersome and error-prone compared to using the GUI which will check you've got everything right before it lets you proceed!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, there is a serious disclaimer on this: I've **not** regression tested the solution (yet), so make sure to read through till the end, understand what I did, test it on a dummy setup with your specific supporting (backup) software and do **not** try this the fist (or second) time around on your most valuable database server production instance you have running.

To take this dilemma head-on, you have to realize that the Always-On Availablity Group as a matter of fact is not a SQL entity, but actually a cluster resource. SQL Server Management Studio was not written with renaming in mind, but on the backend, what SQL Server does, is create cluster resources. The way you would be able to change it, is thus through the Failover Cluster Manager tooling. The first steps I took, was using the GUI here, but - as you will notice on step 3 - there is a tiny part that you cannot change though GUI. Surely the first 2 steps should be scriptable as well, but let's admit: How often will one have do it, and is that actually worth the time finding out?

So, onto the GUI then...

1. First, go to Failover Cluster Manager, go to the roles-node in the object tree and doubleclick the AO-Groupname you wish to change the name of. In the general tab, you can change the role-name. This is also the object name shown in SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Next, having still selected the AO-groupname, go to the Rerouces tab in the lower half of the screen. There you'll find the "Server Name", matching the old AO-Groupname. Make the same adjustment here. Note that this is effectively also renaming the computerObject for the resource in Active Directory. Be sure to have the relevant permissions or it'll fail. Whilst changing that, you will now also be able to see that in DNS the new name is registered for your AO name.
3. Finally, doubleclick on the "Other Resources" object with the name of your new AO group name and check the dependencies tab. You will notice something like NewName_OldName" there. This is where powershell comes to play: go to the administrative powershell prompt on one of the cluster members and use the command below to visually check the resourcenames.

Normally an AO-Group should return values like:

```
PS C:\> Get-ClusterResource AOGROUPNAME* | FT -autosize
Name                      State  OwnerGroup   ResourceType
----                      -----  ----------   ------------
AOGROUPNAME               Online AOGROUPNAME  SQL Server Availability Group
AOGROUPNAME_10.1.2.3      Online AOGROUPNAME  IP Address
AOGROUPNAME_AOGROUPNAME   Online AOGROUPNAME  Network Name
```

Assuming that the AO-Groupname OLDNAME was changed to NEWNAME, you would however now see:

```
PS C:\> Get-ClusterResource NEWNAME* | FT -autosize
Name                  State  OwnerGroup   ResourceType
----                  -----  ----------   ------------
NEWNAME               Online NEWNAME      SQL Server Availability Group
NEWNAME_10.1.2.3      Online NEWNAME      IP Address
NEWNAME_OLDNAME       Online NEWNAME      Network Name
```

This is a final remnant of the old naming, and can be fixed by using the powershell command:

```
PS C:\> Get-ClusterResource "NEWNAME_OLDNAME"| % { $_.Name="NEWNAME_NEWNAME"}
```

You will not get feedback here, but repeating the command to show the original resource names will convince you that the resource name actually was changed.

***Disclamer:***
Mind you, as mentioned at the start, this has not (yet) been tested for compatibility. From my scenario, all appears to work well, but still...

Also you may encounter severe issues whilst changing when the name you are changing into allready has a matching computer object in AD or a manually added A- or CNAME-record in DNS. Make absolutely sure (tripple-check) there are none, or you certainly will meet error messages and possibly a messed-up cluster resource database with strange names. I did have manual A-records, so I had to go in a little further to make sure everything got back in place where it should.